# Ionic 3 angular check how many checkboxes are checked in a dynamic list

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, ionic3

In my application I would like to show a certain number of checkboxes and check how many of them are checked before showing a button.
Other answers suggest to check for each checkbox using `myCheckbox.isChecked()`, but I do not now a priori how many of them I will have, since they represents tags that I fetch from a database, so they do not have a specific ID.
Is there a way to use an ngFor on the list?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have an array of booleans that is binded with the checkboxes (one boolean per checkbox)

create a function in the controller like

```
function atLeast(no) { return this.boolArray.filter(e => e).length >= no }
```

and call it on the ng-show/hide/if check inside the template:

```
<my-fancy-repeater>
    <checkbox ng-repeat="value in $ctrl.boolArray track by $index" ng-model="value"></checkbox>
</my-fancy-repeater>
<my-fancy-button ng-show="$ctrl.atLeast(4)"></my-fancy-button>
```

ofc, i don't know if you're using components, native elements or whatever but this should give the idea

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How do I set true/false on the correspondent position of the array when a checkbox is checked?